# How to make disappearing header have slow transition upon disappearing

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a header that disappears when the user scrolls down, and reappears when the user scrolls up. I was successful in getting the header to reappear with a slow transition, but I am unable to implement the same transition when it disappears. instead it disappears instantly which is not the intended function. I want it to have a 0.5s ease-in-out transition when disappearing like it does when it reappears. Could someone please help me create the desired effect?

```js
 ////Header scroll effect//////

    // Hide Header on on scroll down
    var didScroll;
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    var delta = 10;
    var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        didScroll = true;
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        if (didScroll) {
            hasScrolled();
            didScroll = false;
        }
    }, 250);

    function hasScrolled() {
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        
        // Make sure user scroll more than delta
        if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
            return;
        
        // If user scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav_up.
        if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
            // Scroll Down Disappear
            $('header').removeClass('header__top').addClass('nav_up');
            $('label').removeClass('menu__btn').addClass('nav_up');
        } else {
            // Scroll Up Reappear
            if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
                $('header').removeClass('nav_up').addClass('header__top');
                $('label').removeClass('nav_up').addClass('menu__btn');
            }
        }
        
        lastScrollTop = st;
    }
```

```css
body{
  height: 30000px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: white;
}
.header__top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 5;
  border-bottom: 0.02rem solid #000 ;
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
  transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.nav_up { /*---scroll up effect---*/
  top: -120px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<header class="header__top">
   <p>header</p>
</header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you remove the class `header__top` from element it also removes the transition properties. To avoid that you can add the target class and then remove the old class as a callback function:

```js
////Header scroll effect//////

    // Hide Header on on scroll down
    var didScroll;
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    var delta = 10;
    var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        didScroll = true;
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        if (didScroll) {
            hasScrolled();
            didScroll = false;
        }
    }, 250);

    function hasScrolled() {
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        
        // Make sure user scroll more than delta
        if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
            return;
        
        // If user scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav_up.
        if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
            // Scroll Down Disappear
            $('header').addClass('nav_up',function(){$('header').removeClass('header__top')})
            $('label').removeClass('menu__btn').addClass('nav_up');
        } else {
            // Scroll Up Reappear
            if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
                $('header').removeClass('nav_up').addClass('header__top');
                $('label').removeClass('nav_up').addClass('menu__btn');
            }
        }
        
        lastScrollTop = st;
    }
```

```css
body{
  height: 30000px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: white;
}
.header__top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 5;
  border-bottom: 0.02rem solid #000 ;
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
  transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.nav_up { /*---scroll up effect---*/
  top: -120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<header class="header__top">
   <p>header</p>
</header>
</body>
```